# What different options do we have for displaying profile pictures?

Tags: support, profile-picture

Moments ago, I stumbled with this broken profile picture and noticed it is from `facebook.com`:
[image]

Browsing a bit more I found other host sites (e.g `googleusercontent.com`) are being used. But when I try to change my picture, I only see options from:

- Gravatar
- Uploaded picture
- Identicon

And using the option **Upload a new picture** > **link from the web** re-hosts the images to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/...`, so that's not how they accomplished that.

From which sites can profile pictures be hosted from, and what are the steps needed for this to happen?

Comment: also, I'm not worried about the broken picture, I looked into the 70~ questions with `profile-picture` tag and it does seem to happen from time to time with the facebook ones

Comment: I'm thinking that those are linked only if the user is registering and logging in with their facebook credentials or with the google credentials instead of typing in login information every time, but I've never looked it up to see if that's the case.

Comment: In case you are curious, those images fail to load because of Firefox Tracking Protection. It was reported on MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316284/384394) :)

Comment: See [New! Smarter profile creation and syncing](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/239619) for why accounts sometimes have Facebook or Google profile pictures. You can't later on opt to use your FB or Google profile image, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I noticed until now that the meta link from stackoverflow didn't take me to meta-stackexchange (I could swear years ago it did?) anyway, do you think there is any chance this can get migrated to there :v?

Comment: I don't see a need to migrate this, it is fine here. Not sure about what 'meta link' you mean, this is the Meta site for SO however. Meta.SE is the uber-meta, and a separate site.

Answer (score 2):

Go to to tab to edit your profile and click on "Change picture" and then "upload new picture":

[image]

Then click "link from the web" (or upload a file if you want imgur to host it for you):

[image]

At that point you can have an image hosted from anywhere.

Comment: This will re-upload the image to Imgur. I'm not sure if it's really what OP is asking.

Comment: I think the question is more *how and when does an account end up using the Facebook or Google provided profile picture?*

Comment: I did some testing and what TheWanderer says is true, this will re-host to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/...`

Comment: To clarify here: it happens when their image URL comes from the OAuth provider during signup - that's the only time such URLs can land in our system. We only allow (or even could allow) uploading to the providers in this answer.